# Partial mocking on class that do not follow SOLID principles (especially Dependency Injection)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I have an example class "A" which I am unit testing. I need to dictate the behaviour of class "X" such that it gives me a random number that I specified in my unit tests, than a generated value. I am not sure which class should I mock, I need to have the behaviour of X as it is except for the method "getGen()" it inherits from the abstract class "Y" or is there any other way for me to do what I want to do.

Also, how stupid of an idea is it to override "getGen()" in class X, just for unit testing my code? or is my code un-testable?

Testing class A:

```
class A {
   public Type method(Typ1 a) {
      //do something
      X x = new X(a, String a);
      x.doSmething();
      //do something?
   }
}
```

Class X:

```
final class X extends Y {
   Typ1 t;
   String x;
   X(Typ1 t, String x) {
   this.t = t;
   this.x = x;
   }
   public void doSomething() {
      int x = getGen().method(x);
      //do something
   }
}
```

Abstract class y:

```
abstract class Y {
  Obj getGen(){
    return someInstanceOfObj;
  }
}
```

Obj class:

```
class Obj {
  int method(){
    return someNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: If x.something() returns void, then why do you want to mock its internal behavior? If you just intend to test Class A, then the internals of X are irrelevant. Maybe you actually want to test the behavior of class X and its doSomethins() method?

Answer (score 1):

You omitted almost all visibility modifiers, so I assume all is `package private except`doSomething()`.

In that case place you unittest in the same package as class `Y` and test class `X` (of cause you have to remove the `final` keyword from class `X`):

```
@Test
public void doSomething_delegatesToObj(){
   // arrange
   X x = Mockito.spy(new X());
   Obj o = mock(Obj.class);
   doReturn(o).when((Y)x).getObj(); // must be in same package as Y for this.

   // act
   x.doSomething();

   // assert
   verify(o).method(/*not sure what belongs here*/);  
}
```